# Oracle Virtualbox .Net API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, virtualbox

Is it feasible to display virtualbox screen and send keyboard and mouse IO in a browser? E.g I want to be able to control my VMs in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no, but there are other possibilities. There are few projects, like phpvirtualbox, that allows to control your VirtualBox via browser, but they don't support direct IO from mouse and keyboard to VM. Instead, VirtualBox have a remote display function, so you can use various RDP clients to control your VMs, even if your VM guest system doesn't support RDP. You can turn on "remote display" in VM settings.

So only solution is RDP client, but you can use RDP client web apps, like http://freerdp.net/